# Compare a time command result as a number in IF

Tags: bash

My.sh measures execution time in seconds:

```
/usr/bin/time -f '%e'  long-command
```

I need to compare that time, that should be stored in $exptime, to some number, like:

```
 if (( $exptime < 80  ))  ; then
                    echo "OK" ; exit 0
    elif (( $exptime > 80  ))  ; then
                    echo "NOK" ; exit 1
    else echo "error"
    fi
```

I was trying to assign the output of a command to a variable using command substitution `exptime=$()`, and I get the result on console, but it doesn't work to compare that number in this script (0/1 of the script is used further). But, instead of just using the number in IF, script is called 2 more times.

There are many questions on How to set a variable to the output of a command in Bash? but I couldn't figure out the solution.

Comment: `exptime=$(.... 2>&1)`? Note that `time` _is not_ `/usr/bin/time`

Comment: See [BashFAQ #32](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032) re: storing output of regular `time` (not `/usr/bin/time`)

Comment: That said, please _show us_ an example we can run ourselves to see the problem. If your code contain `exptime=$(/usr/bin/time -f '%e' sleep 3)`, and then showed what was actually stored in `exptime` (ideally with something like `declare -p exptime` or `printf 'exptime=%q\n' "$exptime"`), it would be much clearer.

Comment: ...one possibility is that your long command is emitting other content to stdout, so the `exptime` variable contains _both_ `/usr/bin/time`'s output _and_ `long-command`'s output. If you [edit] the question to provide a command you have tested to ensure that we can run it ourselves with no changes whatsoever to see the same behavior as part of the question, it would be much easier to skip the speculation and go direct to an answer.

Comment: (The other thing is that `/usr/bin/time` is provided by your OS vendor, not part of bash, so we need to know what your OS is to be sure we're looking at the behavior of the correct version).

Comment: @KamilCuk, `result=$(anything 2>&1)` is going to leave `result` empty, will it not? (Granted that the built-in `time` is a special case, but afaict we aren't talking about it here). If you were asking the OP if _they_ were doing that redirection (and thus preventing `time`'s output from being stored in stdout)... yup, good question, but I'm not sure it was clear from the comment; a `?` could be "are you using?", but it could also be "have you tried?"

Comment: @Timso, ...that's the other reason we need your question to include runnable code assigning to `exptime`; if there's something like a `2>&1` preventing content from being captured, we need to be able to see it.

Comment: I'm using /usr/bin/time because it works in a single line with -f '%e' to get seconds. Time result for "sleep 3" is 3.00. If can use additional line of TIMEFORMAT=%R and just time command, time result is 3,010. Thanks for pointing. I use Zsh in Ubuntu but script is Bash, I hope that's not the source of a problem. And error for "sleep 3" example with both time variants is: `((: < 80 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "< 80 ")` I guess result needs to be converted to a number?

Comment: For code ` TIMEFORMAT='%R' ; exptime=$(time sleep 3) ;  printf 'exptime=%q\n' "$exptime"`  I get:
3,002
exptime='' . I don't have 2>&1 in command but I don't see a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by avoiding `time` and using just `long-command` followed by `exptime=$SECONDS`.
Script is iterative and SECONDS starts from 0 each time.

Not sure why time works with simple case of `exptime=$( { time  sleep 3 ; } 2>&1 )`, where it's used as number, and not with my `long-command`, where echo shows it's a correct number but later in IF it repeats command with `division by 0 (error token is`....